# EC2 instance types's exact network performance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bandwidth, live-streaming, network-traffic

I cannot find exact network performance details for different EC2 instance types on Amazon. Instead, they are only saying:

- High
- Moderate
- Low

What does this even mean? I especially want to know the exact amount of `Traffic-OUT` on each instance type.

I need to do live streaming and my stream bit rate will be 240kbps. So I need to know which instance type can handle how many concurrent viewers.

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/a/326797/254651

Comment: You can google for third-party benchmarks. E.g. http://serverfault.com/a/775998/26447

Comment: Related twitter thread about EC2's "up to" network performances: https://twitter.com/dvassallo/status/1120171727399448576

Answer (score 254):

### **Bandwidth is tiered by instance size, here's a comprehensive answer:**

For t2/m3/c3/c4/r3/i2/d2 instances:

- t2.nano = ???  (Based on the scaling factors, I'd expect 20-30 MBit/s)
- t2.micro = ~70 MBit/s (qiita says 63 MBit/s) - t1.micro gets about ~100 Mbit/s
- t2.small = ~125 MBit/s (t2, qiita says 127 MBit/s, cloudharmony says 125 Mbit/s with spikes to 200+ Mbit/s)
- *.medium = t2.medium gets 250-300 MBit/s, m3.medium ~400 MBit/s
- *.large = ~450-600 MBit/s (the most variation, see below)
- *.xlarge = 700-900 MBit/s
- *.2xlarge = ~1 GBit/s +- 10%
- *.4xlarge = ~2 GBit/s +- 10%
- *.8xlarge and marked specialty = 10 Gbit, expect ~8.5 GBit/s, requires enhanced networking & VPC for full throughput

[m1 small, medium, and large instances tend to perform higher than expected.](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/benchmarks/benchmarking-network-performance-of-m1-and-m3-instances-using-iperf-tool)  c1.medium is another freak, at 800 MBit/s.

I gathered this by combing [dozens](https://developer.washingtonpost.com/pb/blog/post/2015/12/02/running-network-constrained-applications-on-ec2/) of [sources](http://epamcloud.blogspot.com/2013/03/testing-amazon-ec2-network-speed.html) doing [benchmarks](http://cloudspectator.com/wp-content/uploads/report/iaas_generational_aws_c3_c4.compressed.pdf) (primarily using iPerf & TCP connections). Credit to [CloudHarmony](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudharmony/iperf_1_0/aws:ec2/%20iperf%20tcp%20test%20report) & [flux7](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://blog.flux7.com%20network%20performance%20analysis&gws_rd=ssl) in particular for many of the benchmarks (note that those two links go to google searches showing the numerous individual benchmarks).

### Caveats & Notes:

The large instance size has the most variation reported:

- m1.large is ~800 Mbit/s (!!!)
- t2.large = ~500 MBit/s
- c3.large = ~500-570 Mbit/s (different results from different sources)
- c4.large = ~520 MBit/s (I've confirmed this independently, by the way)
- m3.large is better at ~700 MBit/s
- m4.large is ~445 Mbit/s
- r3.large is ~390 Mbit/s

**Burstable (T2) instances appear to exhibit burstable networking performance too:**

- The CloudHarmony iperf benchmarks show initial transfers start at 1 GBit/s and then gradually drop to the sustained levels above after a few minutes. PDF links to reports below:
- [t2.small](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudharmony/iperf_1_0/aws:ec2/t2.small/us-west-1/2015-10-22/5573/760779-1/report.pdf) (PDF)
- [t2.medium](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudharmony/iperf_1_0/aws:ec2/t2.medium/us-west-2/2015-10-22/5578/760777-1/report.pdf) (PDF)
- [t2.large](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudharmony/iperf_1_0/aws:ec2/t2.large/eu-west-1/2015-10-22/5580/760760-1/report.pdf) (PDF)

Note that these are within the same region - if you're transferring across regions, real performance may be much slower.  Even for the larger instances, I'm seeing numbers of a few hundred MBit/s.

Comment: Caveat here: AWS seems to be increasing bandwidth slowly over time.  These numbers may increase year over year (although I suspect the 1/2/10 GBit connections will not, since they are probably pegged to hardware).

Comment: Do you have any info about the m4.xlarge instance?

Comment: @JeremyGlover It fits the bounds bars for the xlarge type

Comment: When you say bandwidth is bound by "instance-size", does it mean adding more ENIs (to instances that support this) do not increase the overall throughput ? This is what I am seeing on c4.large instances, and was looking for some validation.

Comment: @Abhinav From the ENI documentation: "Attaching another network interface to an instance (for example, a NIC teaming configuration) cannot be used as a method to increase or double the network bandwidth to or from the dual-homed instance."

Comment: For Azure cloud comparison that is the link https://azure-in-action.blog/2017/01/01/azure-vm-network-bandwidth-tests/ Azure is look like much better.

Comment: @Alexsandro_xpt It does seem that way -- from what I've seen no one cloud provider offers the best value for any particular resource (cpu, memory, storage, network bandwidth).  Looks like Azure might be the network value provider?

Comment: I don't know @BobMcGee, I know the VM network speed in Azure is faster.

Comment: @Alexsandro_xpt Sorry, I wasn't clear: I mean that Azure has an edge on network -- different providers offer the best value in different resources (for example: AWS's compute is pretty reasonable and the burstable instances are good... but their storage pricing is AWFUL).

Comment: What unit is being discussed here? Answer goes back and forth between MBps and Mbps, which are different by a factor of 8.

Comment: If anyone knows bandwidth on t3 instances, it would be good info to share here.

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks like something that took significant time and effort, and it was really helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately flux7 was shut down and all the links are dead. Apart from this, a cursory test seems to indicate that at least some of these numbers are still broadly true in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) supports streaming as well. Might be better than plain streaming from instances.

Answer (score -1):

Almost everything in EC2 is multi-tenant. What the network performance indicates is what priority you will have compared with other instances sharing the same infrastructure.

If you need a guaranteed level of bandwidth, then EC2 will likely not work well for you.

Comment: `If you need a guaranteed level of bandwidth, then EC2 will likely not work well for you.` ?? Then what will guarantee me?

Comment: Multitenant just means there's some variation, it does *not* mean you won't be guaranteed a certain level of resources (and on average get more than that).

Comment: There are dedicated options in EC2, it is a matter of cost.