# Amazon EC2 how to install ixgbevf on a Centos 7 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install the ixgbevf on a Amazon EC2 CentOS7 instance. The steps looks good, but everytime when I run the instance in a Enhanced Networking enabled type, such as M4.xlarge, the network seems fail(I can not connect to the instance after startup).

Here's what I did:

```
wget http://elrepo.org/linux/elrepo/el7/x86_64/RPMS/kmod-ixgbevf-2.16.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh kmod-ixgbevf-2.16.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
cp -p /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img.bak
dracut -f
```

Then shutdown the instance, and set the sriov

```
ec2-modify-instance-attribute instance_id --sriov simple
```

That all. Whenever the type(such as T2.micro) doesn't support Enhanced Networking, the instance works fine. But if I change the type to Enhanced Networking enabled(such as M4.xlarge), the instance simply can't be accessed. Anyone have any idea about this? Did I miss something?

Comment: unfortunately, I havent found the answer. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer lies buried into this section of the original documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html#enhanced-networking-linux

In a nutshell, CentOS 7 already ships with the ixgbevf module, although not with the latest version, but this is hardly a problem. What was causing my instance to be unreachable after a reboot were the "predictable network interfaces", enabled by default.

To disable them, simply visit that link, jump **straight** to step number 6 and type:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -e '^systemd-[0-9]\+\|^udev-[0-9]\+'
$ sudo sed -i '/^GRUB\_CMDLINE\_LINUX/s/\"$/\ net\.ifnames\=0\"/' /etc/default/grub
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

After that:

1. Stop the instance
2. Enable the Enhanced Networking via the aws CLI
3. Restart it

You should now be able to log in!

Comment: Works perfectly. The only sadness is that after turning this on, I didn't see network performance improvement using iperf test. Maybe centos 7 already come with the optimal network interface config?

Comment: You saved my bacon. I couldn't get back into my instance. I panicked as I created a new instance and reassigned the volumes.

Comment: @anastymous glad it worked for you! I know how does it feel to not be able to access an EC2 instance ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, following aws document, I waste a lot of time to install `ixgbevf` module on CentOS 7 AMI Image, that didn't realize I can skip most steps and run the last three commands to resolve this issue directly.

Comment: @khtwo regarding not seeing a performance increase... I deployed two instances in the same AZ in a Placement Group and used iperf3 for testing. I only found a noticeable increase in raw performance when using instance types with 10 Gigabit networking. But, note that Enhanced Networking has other benefits, such as ["lower inter-instance latencies and very low network jitter"](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#enhanced-networking).

Comment: Here's a one-liner that you can run to disable udev's "predictable network interfaces" in the Grub config that will check versions and if it's necessary before editing: `if [[ $( rpm -q systemd | awk -F\- '{print $2}' ) -gt 197 ]] && ! ( grep -q -E '^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX[[:blank:]]*.*net\.ifnames=0' /etc/default/grub ); then sed -e '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/ s/[[:blank:]]*net\.ifnames=.[[:blank:]]*//' -e '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/ s/"$/ net.ifnames=0"/' -i /etc/default/grub && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg ; fi`

Comment: @alanthing I thinks it's because even 2xlarge instance is limit to 1G networks [1] , so a vif driver is enough.
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507405/ec2-instance-typess-exact-network-performance)

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle Linux 6.9 (same as RHEL6/CENTOS6), in a aws placement group running iperf3 between two r2.xlarge instances, i got just shy of  2.5Gbps. ethtools reports vif but the ixgbevf driver is installed. Without SRIOV set to simple, most instances seem to get 1Gbps max.

```
[  4] local 10.11.5.61 port 52754 connected to 10.11.5.222 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   268 MBytes  2.25 Gbits/sec   56    559 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   54    629 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   61    551 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   62    454 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   55    551 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   288 MBytes  2.42 Gbits/sec   50    454 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   291 MBytes  2.44 Gbits/sec   55    559 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   55    507 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   60    472 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec   59    559 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  2.85 GBytes  2.45 Gbits/sec  567             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  2.85 GBytes  2.45 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

Note speeds are slower between different familys even in a placement group as they may have to be placed on different machines.

You can also look at adding ENA interfaces to see if you get better speeds on m4 and c4 instances. Also this is the only support networking on newer instance types m5 and c5.