# Amazon EC2 Upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]We are considering upgrading from an t2.micro AWS server instance to a m3.medium instance based on the recommendation here and some research offline. We feel the need to upgrade primarily for speed issues and to ensure google bots crawl our fast growing site fast enough. We have upward of 8000 products (on magento) and that will grow.

While trying to understand what exactly could be the constraint of the current t2.micro instance, we ran through a lot of logs but couldn't find anything specific that could indicate a bottle-neck as such in the current usage.

Could anyone help point out
1. What are the clues that can be found in logs which could show potential bottleneck issues(if-any) with the current t2.micro instance
2. How could we find out if google-bot had issues while crawling and stopped crawling due to server performance related issues.

Comment: This question is very broad, and depending on how your application is architected and what your infrastructure looks like, the answers will vary. Have you taken a look at the basic Cloudwatch metrics that Amazon EC2 provides? How do your I/O, network bandwidth, and CPU resource look for the last several hours, weeks, etc.? Can your site benefit from a CDN or some type of proxy/caching? Have you done load/performance testing to see what kind of traffic the site can handle? Also note that `t2.micro` are subject to varying performance compared to larger instances because of how EC2 works.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes we use CDN and speedtests are reasonably good(87 on google speed insights). I will post my cloudwatch results here shortly. We don't currently do load/performance testing and will probably do that shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to note about `t2.micro` instances:

- They have CPU limitations based upon a CPU credits system
- They have limited network bandwidth

**CPU credits**

The T2 family is very powerful (see [comparison between `t2.medium` and `m3.medium`](https://youtu.be/8lFT1PqiGB0?t=1570)), but there is a limit on the amount of CPU that can be used.

From the [T2 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits):

> Each T2 instance starts with a healthy initial **CPU credit balance** and then continuously (at a millisecond-level resolution) receives a set rate of CPU credits per hour, depending on instance size. The accounting process for whether credits are accumulated or spent also happens at a **millisecond-level resolution**, so you don't have to worry about overspending CPU credits; a short burst of CPU takes a small fraction of a CPU credit.

Therefore, you should look at the CloudWatch `CPUCreditBalance` metric for the instance to determine whether it has consumed all available credits. If so, then the CPU will be limited to 10% of the time and you either need a larger T2 instance, or you should move away from the T2 family.

In general, T2 instances are great for bursty workloads, where the CPU only spikes at certain times. It is not good for sustained workloads.

**Network Bandwidth**

Each Amazon EC2 instance type has a limited amount of network bandwidth. This is done to prevent *noisy neighbour* situations. While AWS only describes bandwidth as Low/Moderate/High, there are some better details at: [EC2 Instance Types's EXACT Network Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507405/ec2-instance-typess-exact-network-performance)

You can [monitor network traffic of your EC2 instances using CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html). Pay attention to `NetworkIn` and `NetworkOut` to determine whether the instances are hitting limits.

Comment: That is an excellent answer. I have put a chart on my CPU usage and looks like I will not need to upgrade after all. Based on this chart we think we will not upgrade until we come down to the 50 CPU credits (from the current 120) - Would that be an ok way to go about it ? With regard to to Network Bandwidth, we are still making sense of the chart we have and will post it shortly. Thanks again.

Comment: Correct -- the chart suggests that CPU is not a bottleneck for you. The bursty nature of your workload means that you are taking full advantage of the CPU when you need it and you are maintaining a healthy credit balance.