# AWS EC2 network and Disk performance metrics interpretations?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to figure out slow speed of our website for which looking at EC2 performance.
I have a t2.medium instance. CPU metrics are good but I am not able to infer anything from the network metrics.

[image: EC2 Network Metrics]
Above graphs show network usage but I am unable to find the network usage limit for t2.medium instance. At some places I have read that AWS doesn't impose any limit on this, in such a scenario what insights regarding website speed I can get from above?

Also, I am using EBS as root device type. Since the 'Burst Balance' is always 100% can I assume that there is no bottleneck here?

Comment: Check CPU credit balance.  You said "CPU metrics" but it's worth verifying that you considered this one.

Comment: Yes, by "CPU metrics" I meant CPU Utilization, CPU Credit Usage and CPU Credit Balance.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to network performance, I believe there is a pretty extensive explanation in this question: [EC2 Instance Types's EXACT Network Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507405/ec2-instance-typess-exact-network-performance)

With regards to the `Burst Balance`, yes, having it at 100% means you have not hit any limits there. 
That's what the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2) say and this is what their [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/) also explained.

Comment: I have seen network discussion you refereed to but I want to know how to get insights, if any from above network graphs