# Elastic Beanstalk NetworkOut auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have an Elastic Beanstalk app running on t2.medium with autoscaling enabled. EB automatically sets a default autoscale trigger of 6,000,000 bytes over a 5 minute period on NetworkOut. We have a meeting app, so many people load the page at the same time, this causes a spike of NetworkOut data for probably a 10 minute period.

The only place I can get info on what the bandwidth of a t2.medium instance is here:

[EC2 instance types's exact network performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507405/ec2-instance-typess-exact-network-performance)

This says 250-300 MBit/s, which over 5 minutes is a much larger amount of data (~9Gb, unless my calculations are wrong).

I possibly incorrectly assumed EB would set a sensible figure for autoscaling but this seems miles out. Do you think it's safe to increase the autoscaling trigger to something closer to the available bandwidth?

Answer (score 12):

The default NetworkOut alarms are kind of silly - the <2,000,000 one in particular, since it often leads to frequent termination/rebuild of low-use instances.

I believe, however, what the >6,000,000 alarm is alerting on is that outgoing bandwidth from your instance(s) has exceeded 6Mbit/min for five consecutive minutes. That's still well below the maximum bandwidth in the SO post you linked, but not quite as egregious as 6MBit total for five minutes.

Regardless, there's no right or wrong answer - every application is going to have different alarm criteria. I would suggest that you gradually increase the alarm threshold while monitoring your instance's performance until you find an appropriate level that provides a good user experience with over-alerting.

Comment: Thanks, the traffic on the website is low, probably an absolute maximum of 30 sessions at any one time and the server is doing very little apart from serving 4 - 10Mb of static files (big presentations!) to each. Nearly all our data transfer goes through 3rd party servers. I have checked and CPU usage is always low. I'm going to up the threshold quite a lot as I don't think I need new instances for the small bursts when people first load the page. Hopefully there is enough bandwidth to handle this.